# How to re-bind an unbound link/object

Tags: jquery, bind, unbind

By pressing the first button, you will animate the `margin-left` of the second one, by pressing the second one, you unbind the click event from the first one, but I want lets say a third button to bind the click event back to the first one.

Looking for a simple solution of course!

This is what the code looks like:

```
<div class="button"><a href="http://www.google.com">something</a></div>
<div class="button2"><a href="http://www.google.com">something2</a></div>
<div class="button3"><a href="http://www.google.com">something3</a></div>

​(function(){
    $('.button a').on('click', function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
        $('.button2').animate({'margin-left': '+=2'}, 100);       
    })

    $('.button2').on('click', function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         $('.button a').unbind('click');       
    })

    $('.button3').on('click', function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         $('.button a').bind('click');       
    })

})();​
```

and you can mess around with it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Amsjn/)

Comment: I would bind everything and leave them bound. Handle activity with conditional logic in the event handlers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually use named functions in `.on()`. What this means is that you can define a function `marginFunc()`, and then bind it to the click using

```
function marginFunc() {
 ...
}

$(someElement).on('click', marginFunc);
```

Then once you are done, you can unbind it using either `.unbind('click', marginFunc)` **or** `.off('click', marginFunc)`.
Afterwards, you can rebind in the same fashion as you did at the beginning.

[Working jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Amsjn/2/).